# Efiicient way to show 'Cant access network' View with 'Retry' and additional options like 'Wifi Settings', 'Mobile Network'

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, view, loading, android-volley

I need to include this in my app

[image: No Connection]

> When should it get triggered?

- Any action triggered by user from UI requires internet and there's no internet
- Any background activities (like asynchronous loading of images) requiring internet has no internet
- **NOT** when the app is idle or background/user actions **not** requiring internet are being processed

> What I tried?

1. I use **Volley**. Triggered `AlertDialog` inside `Response.ErrorListener` of Volley, everytime I wrote a `JsonObjectRequest`

***Problem**: too repetitive, had too many lines of AlertDialog code*

2. Added a common class called `Alerts` and called the `AlertDialog` from it like

   ```
   DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickTryAgain = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           Swift.getInstance(ProfileActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
       }
   };
   if(error instanceof TimeoutError) Alerts.timeoutErrorAlert(ProfileActivity.this, onClickTryAgain);
   else if(error instanceof NoConnectionError) Alerts.internetConnectionErrorAlert(ProfileActivity.this, onClickTryAgain);
           else Alerts.unknownErrorAlert(ProfileActivity.this);
   ```

My Alerts.class

```
    public class Alerts {


        public static void internetConnectionErrorAlert(final Context context, DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickTryAgainButton) {
            String message = "Sometimes the internet gets a bit sleepy and takes a nap. Make sure its up and running then we'll give it another go";
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
                    .setTitle("Network Error")
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("Try Again", onClickTryAgainButton)
                    .setNegativeButton("Turn Internet On", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }

        public static void timeoutErrorAlert(Context context, DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickTryAgainButton) {
            String message = "Are you connected to internet? We guess you aren't. Turn it on and we'll rock and roll!";
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
                    .setTitle("Network Error")
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("Try Again", onClickTryAgainButton)
                    .show();
        }

        public static void unknownErrorAlert(Context context) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
                    .setTitle("Server Error")
                    .setMessage("We all have bad days! We'll fix this soon...")
                    .setPositiveButton("Hmm, I understand", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

***Problem**: `Try again` button doesn't do what I wanted. Well, **assuming someone gives a fix for that**, I can say, it just replaced some 30 lines of code with 5 lines, well, but what about the transitions? I need to say `connecting`, till response arrives*

3. This time, I added a layout called `ConnectingLayout` covering the whole of the screen.

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
       android:id="@+id/loading_layout"
       android:visibility="gone">

       <ProgressBar
           style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:indeterminate="true" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/loading"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:textSize="25sp"
           android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
           android:singleLine="true" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/loading_description"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
           android:singleLine="true" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

and used it as in

```
    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, getString(R.string.api_root_path) + "/profile", getJson(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                if(response.getBoolean("success")) {
                    Animations.fadeOut(loadingLayout,500);
                    Animations.fadeIn(mainLayout,500);
                    JSONObject dataJson = response.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONObject userJson = dataJson.getJSONObject("user");
                    name.setText(userJson.getString("name"));
                    dob.setText(userJson.getString("dob").equals("null")?null:userJson.getString("dob"));
                    email.setText(userJson.getString("email"));
                    phone.setText(userJson.getString("mobile_no"));
                    promotionOffers.setChecked(userJson.getBoolean("offers"));
                } else {
                    Alerts.requestUnauthorisedAlert(ProfileActivity.this);
                    System.out.println(response.getString("error"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickTryAgain = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    VolleyBaseClass.getInstance(ProfileActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
                }
            };
            if(error instanceof TimeoutError) Alerts.timeoutErrorAlert(ProfileActivity.this, onClickTryAgain);
            else if(error instanceof NoConnectionError) Alerts.internetConnectionErrorAlert(ProfileActivity.this, onClickTryAgain);
            else Alerts.unknownErrorAlert(ProfileActivity.this);
            System.out.println("Response Error: " + error);
        }
    });
    Animations.fadeIn(loadingLayout, 500);
    Animations.fadeOut(mainLayout, 500);
    VolleyBaseClass.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Assume that `Animations.fadeIn(View view, int ms);` and `Animations.fadeOut(View view, int ms);` are properly defined and does the job.

***Problem**: Pain of repeating layouts in all acivities and writing code to fade*

4. Learnt about `ViewStub`s. Generated code programmatically to get the same `ConnectingLayout`. Now I can change text like saving, loading, etc.

***Problem**: Not a big leap, but...  .., it's one more stepping stone I just landed on*

5. I don't need to say its connecting or loading, I just need to say 'Hey, your phone is processing someething'. So I just thought why not use the loading circle in [SwipeRefreshLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/.../SwipeRefreshLayout.html)s ?

***Problem**: Great, it shows little loading circular notch on top, and if loading fails, i can call the alert, **but where is turn wifi on, turn 3G on and other things**, too big for an `AlertDialog` to accommodate all that, is there any other way to show `try again`?*

6. Looked about using `same fragment in all activities` and `redirecting to a callActivityForResult` (sorry that I can't add more than two links)

***Problem**: Hmm...! Taking the user to a new activity is what I find eating resources and bringing down performance considerably. And fragments?*

> I am not giving up! I know I'm learning it the hard way, but with great hopes that the developer community will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Volley **DETROYS all listeners** as soon as it receives something from the server, regardless of whether the response is a proper response or an error response.

A request needs to constructed everytime it should be sent or resent.

These steps will help achieve it

- Create a fragment with `Retry` and other necessary buttons like `Wifi Settings`, `Mobile Network Settings`
- Create a full sized `FrameLayout` inside `RelativeLayout` on necessary views **to accommodate the fragment created** and hide it initially
- When request fails, make the `FrameLayout` visible and the retry button should call the function that **constructs and calls** the request

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same needs and issues. I am working on a Volley based library [jus](https://github.com/apptik/jus) where most the issues you have had i handle with rxJava global observables and of course Alerts class with static alerts/views generators. the connectivity handling I try to make it smooth using [ConnectivityManager](https://github.com/apptik/jus/blob/master/jus-java/src/main/java/io/apptik/comm/jus/ConnectivityManager.java) and [NoConnectionPolicy](https://github.com/apptik/jus/blob/master/jus-java/src/main/java/io/apptik/comm/jus/NoConnectionPolicy.java) concepts.